# react-native unable to import react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, babeljs

I am new to reactjs. I am using `react-native` and I wanted to import `react-redux`.
But I keep getting:

> "development server response 500.
>   Message: {transform error: .../node_modules/redux/lib/index.js: 
>   {babel}..../node_modules/redux/lib/index.js:
>   Using removed babel 5 option: .../node_modules/redux/.babelrc.stage - check out the corresponding stage x presets http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets".

My package.json looks like

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.36.0",
    "react-native-pathjs-charts": "0.0.20",
    "react-native-svg": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.3.26",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.5.0",
    "eslint": "2.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "1.3.2"
  }
```

My .babelrc looks like

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native", "stage-0"]
}
```

I am importing in my component like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'


import { connect } from 'react-redux/src/index';
```

Any idea how to import `react-redux` into my component? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `import { connect } from 'react-redux'` ?

Comment: Yeah. I tried that too. Did not work! I also got a different version of react-redux and I tried 'react-redux/native'. but same error

Comment: kind of just taking a stab at the dark here, but you specify react-native in your .babelrc, yet I don't see it in your installed presets in the  package.json.

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved ?